# How to find direction turn by turn using camera in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

Below code is finding edges and yellow lines.Basically I would like to print left turn as yellow line turn left.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, orig_frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        continue

    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(orig_frame, (5, 5), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    low_yellow = np.array([18, 94, 140])
    up_yellow = np.array([48, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, up_yellow)    
    edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 75, 150)

    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50, maxLineGap=50)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:            
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("edges",edges)     
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)
    if key == 27:
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: just find the angle of the line... 0-90 and 180-270 is to the right and 90-180 and 270-360 is to left (using two ranges just in case the points used are not in the desired order)

Comment: Thanks ..but how to find angle of line

Comment: basically atan2 (dy/dx) and dy is the difference between y2-y1 and dx from x2-x1... remember the border case (dx == 0) which is 90 degrees or vertical line. And always check the documentation of the function to see if it is degrees or radians (normally it is radians)